# Virtualization is locked in BIOS

Tags: bios, virtualization, lock

I want to run virtual machines on my computer, my Windows is currently  32-bit and I'm switching to 64, I don't know why they gave it with 32 because It would work with 64.
When I go to the BIOS the option of virtualization is greyed out.
I saw a program telling the things so here's a screenshot:

[image]

Would it work for me when I'll switch to 64-bit?

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400
- 4GB RAM

Comment: Locked refers to whether the BIOS has enabled Intel Trusted Execution Technology (TXT), which uses crypto and the TPM to prevent software from modifying the BIOS image in RAM, and enabling the feature on the fly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology

Comment: Which option did you look at in Bios?

Answer (score 0):

Your processor supports virtualization (VT-x) as can be [confirmed on ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB).

You can install and run the [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838) if you're not convinced. You should see something like this if it's supported:
[image: Intel VT-x supported]

Comment: So It doesn't matters if it's locked but enabled?

Comment: I don't know why it's locked. Maybe you could [try this](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2013481/intel-virtualization-tech-ami-bios-option-greyed.html#12617475) and see if that works for you.

Comment: @BenR More details about your system (make, model, BIOS version, etc.) may be required to figure out how to enable VT-x

Comment: Note that if it says that it's not supported, that can mean that the physical CPU supports it but that it's in use and the virtual CPU does not.

Comment: How I can find these details? and the PC was custom built.
    What do you mean by phisycal and virtual CPU?
    I will try to switch battery, thanks :)

Comment: @BenR you can run this command to get some basic info about your BIOS: `wmic bios get manufacturer, version, BIOSVersion, caption, description` or simply `wmic bios get`

Comment: You'll need to type them into a command prompt. You can start one by pressing `Win`+`R` and entering `cmd` into the **Run** window and press OK.

Comment: @Vinayak I run this command, the CMD windows shows for 1/2 second and closes

Comment: @Vinayak oh here: http://prntscr.com/ajyle0

Comment: @BenR I can't really make out much from that. Could you run `wmic bios get manufacturer, name, version, BIOSVersion, caption, description` instead? Also it doesn't really look like there's any useful information there. Could you post a screenshot/picture of your BIOS screen?

Comment: I have "No" in intel virtualization technology in the intel processor identification utility. So it means i can't run a Virtual machine on my computer??. It is intel core 2 duo E8400

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz That means VT-x won't be supported but you can still run VMs